# Multiple MouseHover events in a Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to implement a custom control in C# and I need to get events when the mouse is hovered. I know there is the MouseHover event but it only fires once. To get it to fire again I need to take the mouse of the control and enter it again.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want an event every time the x/y coordinates change when it is hovering over your control?

Comment: I want to get an event everytime the mouse stops moving. I also hook the MouseMove event, but I need to know when the mouse stops moving. Is there other way to do this than using the MouseHover event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's define "stops moving" as "remains within an `x` pixel radius for `n` ms".

Subscribe to the MouseMove event and use a timer (set to `n` ms) to set your timeout. Each time the mouse moves, check against the tolerance. If it's outside your tolerance, reset the timer and record a new origin.

Pseudocode:

```
Point lastPoint;
const float tolerance = 5.0;

//you might want to replace this with event subscribe/unsubscribe instead
bool listening = false;

void OnMouseOver()
{
    lastpoint = Mouse.Location;
    timer.Start();
    listening = true; //listen to MouseMove events
}

void OnMouseLeave()
{
    timer.Stop();
    listening = false; //stop listening
}

void OnMouseMove()
{
    if(listening)
    {
        if(Math.abs(Mouse.Location - lastPoint) > tolerance)
        {
            //mouse moved beyond tolerance - reset timer
            timer.Reset();
            lastPoint = Mouse.Location;
        }
    }
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //mouse "stopped moving"
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something much simpler using a Timer. It's kind of "hackish" but it gets the job done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @lc: I have a similar implementation, but have not found it necessary to use a "tolerance". Just checking if last mouse location is different from the current one works fine.

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this is an old topic but I wanted to share a way I found to do it: on the mouse move event call ResetMouseEventArgs() on the control that catches the event.

Comment: This is the best answer if you are creating your own custom control class, but won't work for an existing class because ResetMouseEventArgs() is protected. The MouseHover event is simplest way to deal with hovering and using ResetMouseEventArgs() makes it behave the way you would expect it to. Note that you only need to call ResetMouseEventArgs() in MouseHover. Alternatives that use your own timer are easy enough, but messy.

Answer (score 2):

Why not subscribe to the MouseMove events in the MouseHover event, then unsubscribe in the MouseLeave event

Edit:

One way to determine if the mouse is stopped would be to start a timer every time you get a mouse move event, when the timer has elapsed then you could consider the mouse stopped. 
The reason for removing the MouseMove events on MouseLeave would allow you to only receive events while the mouse is over your control.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I already handle the MouseMove event and it only tells me when the mouse is moving, not when it is stopped.

Comment: I had thought about using a timer. I'm gonna try that tomorrow. And I can't use the other option because I need to receive mouse events even when the mouse is outside the control.

Comment: I am talking about the mouse move events for this control only, not the application. If the mouse move events cannot be turned on and off for the control, then you could calculate if the current mouse movement in within the bounds of the control.

Comment: The problem is: this control is the application. It's an OpenGL control that occupies the entire area of the window.

Answer (score 2):

This was the cleanest implementation I could come up with. It works quite well:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage
    (
        IntPtr controlHandle,
        uint message,
        IntPtr param1,
        IntPtr param2
    );

    const uint WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;

    Point lastMousePoint = Point.Empty;

    void richTextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(e.Location.X - lastMousePoint.X) > 1 || Math.Abs(e.Location.Y - lastMousePoint.Y) > 1)
        {
            lastMousePoint = e.Location;

            SendMessage((sender as RichTextBox).Handle, WM_MOUSELEAVE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    void richTextBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly simpler version that doesn't rely on a Timer. Just record the time of the last mouse move then to compare current time whenever you want to check if the mouse is hovering.

```
    private DateTime mouseMoveTime = DateTime.Now;
    private Point mouseMoveLoc = new Point();

    private bool IsHovering()
    {
        return (mouseMoveTime.AddMilliseconds(SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime)).CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0;
    }

    private void myControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // update mouse position and time of last move
        if (Math.Abs(e.X - mouseMoveLoc.X) > SystemInformation.MouseHoverSize.Width || 
            Math.Abs(e.Y - mouseMoveLoc.Y) > SystemInformation.MouseHoverSize.Height)
        {
            mouseMoveLoc = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            mouseMoveTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Or a really short version that doesn't have a distance tolerance.

```
    private DateTime mouseMoveTime = DateTime.Now;

    private bool IsHovering()
    {
        return (mouseMoveTime.AddMilliseconds(SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime)).CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0;
    }

    private void myControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseMoveTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Just use if (IsHovering())... when you need to check if the mouse is moving.

One thing I have noticed though is that MouseMove is not fired when you are dragging. You can however copy the mouseMoveTime/Loc update code to your drag event to get round this.